# java.util.Collection and duplicate elements

Tags: java, collections

From  [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html),

> ***boolean add(E e)***
>
> Ensures that this collection contains the specified element (optional
>   operation). Returns **true** if this collection changed as a result of the
>   call. (Returns **false** if this collection does not permit duplicates and
>   already contains the specified element.)

It only says *"Returns false if this collection does not permit duplicates"*. It doesn't explain whether it should **ignore** the element or **replace** it. As per this phrase *"Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the call"*, I presume that whenever false is returned by this method, it means that the Collection is ignoring the element and no element is replaced, the collection remains as is. Is that correct?

In case of duplicate elements, what is the action performed by java.util.Collection implementing classes which does not permit duplicates? Is it always ignore, or always replace, or it depends on the implementation?

Comment: I think it has to ignore it, otherwise it would have to return true.

Answer (score 5):

Since it returns true when the collection is modified, returning false implies that it hasn't modified the collection, i.e. it hasn't replaced the element.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.

Collections that do not permit duplicates would return false if you were trying to add a duplicate item. Nothing would be modified what-so-ever, it would just be ignored.

If you were writing an implementation for a set, the theory would be this:

Check to see if the set already contains it.
If so, return false.
Else, add element to set, return true.

Answer (score 0):

The question which might not be covered by docs is 'can a collection quickly detect duplicates and store them anyway?'. The answer is yes and and an example can be a [Multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) in Guava in which all duplicates are counted and `Collection.add(obj)` always returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Concrete implementations explain it clearly, eg HashSet.add says "If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false"